# How to round numbers given by cmath

Tags: python, math, string-formatting, complex-numbers, cmath

For the sake of practice, I am trying to build a simple function that solves quadratic roots - including complex roots and returns a nice and rounded result. However, neither the round() function or f-string formatting seems to work.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
from cmath import sqrt

a = float(input("Input ax^2: "))
b = float(input("Input bx: "))
c = float(input("Input c: "))

def quadratic_roots(a,b,c):
    x_1 = (-b - sqrt((b ** 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)
    x_2 = (-b + sqrt((b ** 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)

    return x_1,x_2


print(f"--- {a}x^2 {b}x + {c} = 0 ----")

#Attempting to use round() fuction.
print(f"x_1 = {round(quadratic_roots(a,b,c)[0],2)}")    #Produces error
print(f"x_2 = {round(quadratic_roots(a,b,c)[1],2)}")    #Produces error

#Attempting to use f-string formatting .to round up to three digits.
print(f"x_1 = {quadratic_roots(a,b,c)[0]:.3d}")        #Produces error
print(f"x_2 = {quadratic_roots(a,b,c)[1]:.3d}")        #Produces error
```

And here is the output/error message I'm getting:

```
    print(f"x_1 = {round(quadratic_roots(a,b,c)[0],2)}")
TypeError: type complex doesn't define __round__ method
```

Is there anyone out there who can help me sort this out and return the result as a nice and rounded result?

Any help is welcomed and appreciated :-)

Comment: what was your input values?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, it works fine on my computer: `print(f"x_1 = {quadratic_roots(1,1,1)[0]:.3f}")`
`x_1 = -0.500-0.866j`

Comment: @Sabil: My input was just 1, 1,1 Wich gives a complex number as an result

Comment: @stef: Haha, you are absolutely right! I just figured out my own (stupid) mistake. I used f"{:.d}" which produces the error I posted about, rather than f"{:.f} (which is what I posted, and which does actually work)

Comment: @Stef: So I basically solved my own problem while posting my own post. Haha. But thanks for helping out anyway!

Comment: I resolved your issue @fredericoamigo. Hope now it will work for you

Comment: If it works for you then please accept my answer and give an upvote. :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue was with round. I fix the issue and hope it will work now.

**Code:**

```
from cmath import sqrt

a = float(input("Input ax^2: "))
b = float(input("Input bx: "))
c = float(input("Input c: "))

def quadratic_roots(a,b,c):
    x_1 = (-b - sqrt((b ** 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)
    x_2 = (-b + sqrt((b ** 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)

    return x_1, x_2


print(f"--- {a}x^2 {b}x + {c} = 0 ----")

x_1, x_2 = quadratic_roots(a,b,c)

#Attempting to use round()
print(f"x_1 = {round(x_1.real, 3) + round(x_1.imag, 3) * 1j}")
print(f"x_2 = {round(x_2.real, 3) + round(x_2.imag, 3) * 1j}")

#Attempting to use f-string formatting .to round up to three digits.
print(f"x_1 = {x_1:.3f}")
print(f"x_2 = {x_2:.3f}")
```

**Input:**

```
Input ax^2: 1
Input bx: 1
Input c: 1
```

**Output:**

```
--- 1.0x^2 1.0x + 1.0 = 0 ----
x_1 = (-0.5-0.866j)
x_2 = (-0.5+0.866j)
x_1 = -0.500-0.866j
x_2 = -0.500+0.866j
```

Answer (score 1):

You can round the real and imaginary parts separately and then join them

```
print(f"x_1 = {round(quadratic_roots(a,b,c[0].real,2)}+{round(quadratic_roots(a,b,c)[0].imag,2)*1j}")    
print(f"x_2 = {round(quadratic_roots(a,b,c)[1].real,2)}+{round(quadratic_roots(a,b,c)[1].imag,2)*1j}")
```

Comment: Your answer is suggesting computing FOUR TIMES all the roots? Why not compute just once, and assign the result to variable names?

Comment: @Stef: You're probably rigth. There are absolutely better ways to do this, but as I wrote in the description, this is purely for the sake of practice. I'm just a noob who tries to learn how to code:-)

Answer (score 1):

Complex numbers have a real part and an imaginary part.

Try:

```
x_1 = quadratic_roots(a, b, c)[0].real + quadratic_roots(a, b, c)[0].imag
x_2 = quadratic_roots(a, b, c)[1].real + quadratic_roots(a, b, c)[1].imag


print(f"x_1 = {round(x_1,2)}")
print(f"x_2 = {round(x_2,2)}")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

After some help from the comments, this problem was fixed this by using

```
print(f"x_1 = {quadratic_roots(a,b,c)[0]:.3f}")  
print(f"x_2 = {quadratic_roots(a,b,c)[1]:.3f}")
```

The problem was that I used the wrong f-string formatting:

I tried to use `f"{:.d}"`, which didn't work. Replacing this with `f"{:.f}"` worked just fine.

However, as suggested in the comments, there are better ways of solving this problem.

A massive thank you to everyone who helped out and contributed!